# How to minimize compilation time in C++

Tags: c++

I've coded an script that generates a header file with constants like version, svn tag, build number. Then, I have a class that creates a string with this information.

My problem is the following: As the file is created in every compilation, the compiler detects that the header has changed, and forces the recompilation of a large number of files. I guess that the problem is in the situation of the header file. My project is a library and header has to be in the "interface to the world" header file (it must to be public).

I need some advice to minimize this compilation time or to reduce the files forced to recompile.

Comment: Compilers generally don't "detect" that other files have changed, and trigger re-compilation. That's a higher-level feature, often implemented by the IDE and/or more explicitly in the build system itself (e.g. by Make & co).

Comment: @unwind: You aren't true. Some compilers can detect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the header write something like:

```
extern const char *VERSION;
extern const char *TAG;
extern const char *BUILD_DATE;
```

and create a .c (or .cpp) file that will contain

```
const char *VERSION = "0.13";
const char *TAG = "v_0_13";
const char *BUILD_DATE = "2011-02-02 11:19 UTC+0100";
```

If your script updates the .c file, only that file will have to be recompiled, but the files that include your header won't.

Comment: Thanks for your well documented solution. I was usefull

Answer (score 4):

Generate the constants in the implementation file.

Make sure the header doesn't get changed by your script.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to solve this is to not make those constants in a header file.  Instead, make functions in the header file which get these values.  Then place the values themselves in a small cpp file which implements those functions.  (Or place them in a header ONLY included in that cpp file).  When you recompile, only that one file will need to be recompiled.

Also, you could look in to distcc to speed up compilation if you have a few machines to spare.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using gcc, you can try using [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/). it caches object files based on a hash of the preprocessed output, so will not recompile unless an actual change occured

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to declare the constant values like `extern const double PI;` in your a header like "my_constants.h" and add one cpp file to the project with contents like:

```
#include "my_constants.h"

const double PI = 3.1415926535;
```

Then the actual values will only be compiled once, and changing a value only requires compiling that single file and linking the project again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it as a single public header, you could add a pre-build step that takes your public header file and

- filters out the version details, either removing them or replacing them with a fixed string, to a temp copy of the file
- moves this to an internal version of your header only if it has changed, i.e. don't copy the file (+ update the timestamp) unless something other than the version has changed

then build your precompiled headers from this internal header file. You can still use the public header with the version details for the source files that need the version.

There's a moveifchanged script in the GCC sources you can borrow for this if you're on unix, or you can rig something up using fc in a batch file on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Object oriented solution:

Generally, you should put those often refreshed cnstants to cpp file, not h. Put them for example into a class. If you already have a class which creates a string of them and publish this by a method, I'd put all those constants to the same cpp and added some public methods to access them from other source files.